# Is it possible to view the current file content during directory navigation in vi (command line, not GUI)?

Tags: vim, vi

I am watching [this Pluralsight course on helm](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/kubernetes-packaging-applications-helm/table-of-contents) and the instructor uses vi from the linux console all the time in the **directory browsing mode** with the current file being automatically open for viewing in the other pane:
[image]

When I run **vi .** it does open the directory navigation mode, but I have only one pane and to view a file I need to Enter it and then it shows it **instead** of the directory view. I can go back with `:E`, but the experience is not the same.

How can we tell vi to automatically open the current file in a side pane, so both the directory navigator and the file content are available in side by side panes?

I do not have any vi configuration. This is a fresh new Linux 18.04 VM to which I connect with ssh.

Comment: Consider using the [vi.se] stack for your questions on Vim!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is using the [`:Lexplore`](https://vimhelp.org/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw-%3ALexplore) mode of netrw.

Either open it with `:Lexplore` from inside Vim, or if you want to start Vim with it open, use `vim +Lexplore` (instead of `vim .`), or `vim +Lex` for short.

---

If you prefer to use the "preview" feature, to open the file in the right window while keeping the cursor on the netrw window, then set the following variable:

```
" Open the preview window vertically.
let g:netrw_preview = 1
```

Then open netrw by itself with `vim .` or `:e .` and then use the `p` key to open the file in a "preview" window. The first time you use `p` will open the preview window.

You might want to also set:

```
let g:netrw_preview   = 1
let g:netrw_liststyle = 3
let g:netrw_winsize   = 30
```

See [`:help netrw-preview`](https://vimhelp.org/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw-preview) for details.

Comment: The setup in those slides is also using `let g:netrw_liststyle = 3` for the tree-like display.

Comment: Starting `vi +Lexplore` seems to work, but the file content is not displayed automatically - I have to Enter it. Which is fine, except, the focus is on the file now. How do I get it back to the navigation pane? Or maybe it is possible to show the file automatically without Entering it?

Comment: @mark Answer updated, please take another look! (I don't seem to have easy access to the video you attached, so mostly going by the screenshot.)

Comment: I am going to move my question over to the Vi and Vim forum. Would you mind replicating your answer there? - https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27186/is-it-possible-to-view-the-current-file-content-during-directory-navigation-in-v